# Cut a specific part of a column from a csv file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, perl, csv

I have to process a csv containing about 15 columns one of which contains a particular timestamp that includes milliseconds. When I go to insert this csv into a DB, I get an error because of this particular time format. I can't touch the other columns, but I need to truncate the 6th column's output and create a new file.

An example is:

```
73306758;Da Lavorare;;20300;RESTAROC;10/10/2014 16:37:22.425;PALAGIANO;TA;PUGLIA;;Libretto;IDENTITA;AI2000000;OK;DOC Valido;0;0;CCCMNN85X26X251X;OK;CF Attribuito;0;0
```

Comment: Please always include your desired output as well.

Comment: Is this representative input from the file. A CSV file can have newlines in a fields value and be quoted, have a different field separator than `,`. In general you need a CSV handling library and Perl/Python/Ruby to handle CSV files unless your data is really simplistic.

Comment: Please completely flesh out your Q's before posting them. As it stands you're asking 1 Q above and then changing it mid-stream on comments below while ppl are trying to help you. Always include sample output of what you'd like the results to look like so that it's crystal clear to other's what exactly it is you're looking for.

Comment: Ok sorry to evryone for my mistake. Anyway i solved with
sed 's/.[0-9][0-9][0-9]//g' output1.csv > file.csv
Anyway thx everyone for help!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to remove any cases of `:` followed by numbers from the 4th column (you say the 6th in your question but it's the 4th in your example), you can use one of these:

1. awk

   ```
   awk -F';' -v OFS=";" '{sub(/\.[0-9]*$/,"",$6);}1;' file.csv > new.csv
   ```
2. Perl (this changes the actual file and keeps the original as `file.csv.bak`)

   ```
   perl -i.bak -F';' -ane '$F[5]=~s/\.[0-9]*$//; print join ",", @F' file.csv
   ```

Comment: Uhmmm in the original file there are many columns after i'll post an example line of this file like this you can tell me better. For now i say just thanks

Comment: @fabiousaol85 the number of fields after the one you care about is irrelevant. Just change `$4` to `$N` where `N` is the field you want.

Comment: Hi everyone, this is the file i have to process:
73306758;Da Lavorare;;20300;RESTAROC;10/10/2014 16:37:22.425;PALAGIANO;TA;PUGLIA;;Libretto;IDENTITA;AI2000000;OK;DOC Valido;0;0;CCCMNN85X26X251X;OK;CF Attribuito;0;0
The part i have to truncate is the .425 in the date field.

Comment: i tryied both solutions and it didn't work. According to example i posted previously i used the following command:
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{sub(/.[0-9]*$/,"",$6);}1;' file.csv > new.csv

Comment: @fabiousaol85 that's a completely different thing from what you posted. Your fields are not separated by commas and your milliseconds are not separated from the seconds with `:`. Of course it doesn't work, how could it? Please always post an actual example of your file. Anyway, try the updated version, it should work.